# Enumerating through a list of gameobjects comparing against a group of Enums

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**I wish to find a compact way to accomplish the following using c#'s built in Enumeration functionality** *(in the Collections library)*.

**1.** Enumerate through a list of gameObjects getting the name of the current item at each iteration

**2.** with that item, compare the string name against a group of Enums I have created for convenience (to avoid spelling mistakes in strings)

**3.** if the name matches atleast ONE enum, return true and execute content

I often see keywords like *IList<>* and *IEnumerable<>* when writing code and want to understand there use better.

**Pseudocode**

```
foreach(GameObject item in myGameObjectList)
{
   if(item.name.ToLower() == nameof(IEnumerable<MyEnums>(out match /*does the string match?*/))
   {
     //this code will execute if the item in the list has a name matching atleast one of the enums
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you compare strings when you can compare the enum value itself? Just store it on your gameobject. A numeric comparision is much faster than a string comparision.

Comment: The reason is, this is for the Editor and isn't intended to be incredibly optimized, its intended to be convenient for configuring things before building, this code is stripped from per-processing at build-time. Adding enums to every game-object this thing is comparing may be cumbersome, and an automated way of doing it would just be wasted effort compared to this.

Comment: check out Linq, that will provide you a way to do what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

I would start by getting the list of enum as an array. To make code look nicer (but a tiny bit slower) we can convert that array to a list, and call `Contains` on it for each name. See this example:

```
 string[] names=System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(MessageType)); 
 List<string> namesList=new List<string>(names); // to be able to use contain

 foreach(GameObject item in myGameObjectList)
      if(namesList.Contains(item.name.ToLower())
          DoStuff();
```

In your actual code, get the list/name array at start, don't do it with each call, as it uses reflection under the hood so is a little bit expensive.

Answer (score 0):

To further my comment about using `Linq`

```
string comparison = "YourEnum";
List<GameObject> matches = objects.Where(x => x.name == comparison).ToList();
```

`matches` in the above example would be `GameObjects` that match the enum you provide which you can then do what it is you wish to do if there are any matches.